# how to call high chart in asp.net

Tags: highcharts

how to call high chart in onclientclick asp.net

My java script is

```
 <script >
   function chart () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: true
                }
            },
            //legend: {
            //    layout: 'vertical',
            //    align: 'right',
            //    verticalAlign: 'middle',
            //    borderWidth: 0
            //},
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    };
</script>
```

I am calling above method in onclientclick

```
<asp:Button Text="Show" OnClientClick="chart()" runat="server" />
```

when i click this button chart visible for 1 or 2 sec after that its in visible

where i made error......

Comment: Do you have any errors in javascript console?

Comment: Did you create the `#container` DIV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Load that function on page load